# How to evaluate the integral: $I=\int_1^e\frac{\ln^2x-3\ln x+3}{x\ln x-2x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate this integral: $$I=\int_1^e\frac{\ln^2{x}-3\ln{x}+3}{x\ln{x}-2x}dx$$

Help me, thanks :/

Comment: i think this question need some correction

Comment: Use Wolfram alpha

Comment: wolfram gives $-\frac{1}{2}-\ln(2)$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
substitute $\ln{x}=t$

Denominator gives an $x$, so $\frac{1}{x}dx=dt$

U then have
$\int\frac{t^2}{t-2}dt-\int\frac{3t}{t-2}dt+\int\frac{3}{t-2}dt$

which can be done